# Abstracting away this Factory pattern

Tags: typescript, factory

I'm working on a project that has a number of classes that wrap various AWS services. These wrapper classes all share a common factory pattern (mostly centered around assuming a role) and I'd like to abstract that away so I don't have to copy/paste so much. :) How can I do that?

Example:

```
class ParameterStore { // wraps SSM Parameter Store
  public static Factory({
    assumeRoleArn,
    roleSessionName,
    roleSessionDuration,
    endpoint,
    region,
  }: ParameterStoreFactoryArgs): ParameterStore {
    const params = { endpoint, region };
    let credentials: CredentialsProvider | undefined;
    if (assumeRoleArn) {
      credentials = AssumeRoleCredentialsProvider({ 
        RoleArn: assumeRoleArn,
        RoleSessionName: roleSessionName,
        DurationSeconds: roleSessionDuration ?? 900
      });
    }
    const client = new SSMClient({ credentials, ...params});
    return new ParameterStore(client)
  }
  private constructor(private client: SSMClient) {
    public getParameter(name: string) { }
    public setParameter(name: string, value: string) {}
  }
}
```

```
class Database { // wraps DynamoDB
   public static Factory({
    assumeRoleArn,
    roleSessionName,
    roleSessionDuration,
    endpoint,
    region,
    table
  }: DatabaseFactoryArgs): Database {
    const params = { endpoint, region };
    let credentials: CredentialsProvider | undefined;
    if (assumeRoleArn) {
      credentials = AssumeRoleCredentialsProvider({ 
        RoleArn: assumeRoleArn,
        RoleSessionName: roleSessionName,
        DurationSeconds: roleSessionDuration ?? 900
      });
    }
    const client = new DynamoDBClient({ credentials, ...params});
    return new Database(client)
  }
  private constructor(private client: DynamoDBClient) {}

  public get(key: string) {}
  public put(key: string, value: any) {}
}
```

As you can see, the Factory methods in the two classes are almost identical. What I'd like is to abstract out that common code in both classes so I can do (e.g.):

```
const db = Database.Factory({assumeRoleArn: databaseRole, table: tableName});
const parameters = ParameterStore.Factory({assumeRoleArn: parameterRole});
```

But I want to emphasize that `Database` and `ParameterStore` are just examples. Ideally I would have something like an abstract class that provides the Factory method that I could override in the subclass definitions, but I'm not sure how I'd do that with the AWS client.

Comment: What's an example of the duplication you are trying to fix here?

Comment: Like is this what you want? https://tsplay.dev/m07aPN Not having to to pass in the same config repeatedly?

Comment: @AlexWayne See my edit. Basically I'm looking to have some kind of generic Factory method that has some way of specifying what AWS client I want to use.

Comment: Are the factories doing anything of value? Do you need them?

Comment: @Evert I'm not sure I do, TBH. At one time I think I was assuming the role when the factory was called, but nowadays I pass in a credential handler function which ends up getting called when `client.send()` gets called.

Comment: Well it sounds like the most elegant solution is to remove code then ;) My personal favourite kind of pull request.

Comment: "As you can see, the Factory methods in the two classes are almost identical." No, I don't see that. The factory methods each have two lines, but you call different constructors, with different argument types. What is the pattern here? Are there always two constructors, and you pass one to the other like `new A(new B(params))`? If so you could make a function like to do that for you when provided those two constructors, but I think that's way more complicated than this warrants.

Comment: @AlexWayne The constructors are identical in that they use the exact same code to determine the role, if any, to be assumed. The pattern is always that the Factory takes some superset of `{ assumeRoleArn ... }`, instantiates an AWS service client, and passes the client to the wrapper class.

Comment: @AlexWayne Looking at that again, I've handwaved away all of the assumeRole stuff. Let me go in and clarify that...

Comment: @AlexWayne I think it's clearer now. Both wrapper classes call `AssumeRoleCredentialsProvider()` if `assumeRoleArn` is present and pass that provider (if it exists) to the AWS client.

Comment: @Evert I could certainly merge the Factory methods into the constructors, but it still leaves me with (as you can see in the edited post) a big hunk of duplicated code that I have to test with *every* wrapper class I define.

Comment: I guess I also wonder, why are these classes at all. Why does any of this exist? if this is about the `AssumeRole` stuff, could you move that into its own function that returns `credentials` ?

Comment: @Evert They're classes because I want this application to be easy to port to another cloud. The main idea is that the API *never* interacts directly with AWS. Instead it uses these service classes to provide specific functionality that, while currently backed by AWS, can be switched to another cloud with minimal difficulty.

Comment: I see, so it's an entire abstraction layer? In that case, can you create a separate function anyway that takes `assumeRoleArn`, `roleSessionName`, `etc` and returns valid `credentials` value?

Comment: @Evert I can, but I'd still have to test that the service constructor got passed that `credentials` value, and the whole point of this (which admittedly I haven't stated) is so I can test the AWS client instantiation *once* (except when I override the base params, but i have a thought about that too)

Comment: You know, what I'm ultimately looking for is something like this: `Factory(SSMClient, { assumeRoleArn, ... })`. I've *done* a thing where I passed a class as a parameter in Angular...

Comment: @AureliaPeters if this is about testing, i don't see why you couldn't write a generic test for this as well

Comment: So I've got the AWS stuff, at least, into a function: https://tsplay.dev/Nda9dm . It does everything I want it to do, I think, save for instantiating the wrapper class, but that might be OK, come to think on it.

Comment: You after something like this? https://tsplay.dev/N7zEPw

Comment: @AlexWayne That's pretty close to the thing I just thought up in my previous comment. XD

Comment: @AlexWayne - the solution you linked gives the error `Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamoDBClient'`